What does Empower Metamagic affect?
Feat says:

All variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell are increased by
half including bonuses to those dice rolls.
Saving throws and opposed rolls are not affected, nor are spells
without random variables. An empowered spell uses up a spell slot two
levels higher than the spell's actual level.

What counts as variable though? Dictionary-wise every non-static value, such as "1 per level" is a variable.
And what about "spells without random variables"? There's plenty of spells with dice roll (which is random) that also have plenty of scaling values, not related to this roll at all.
Specific example: Planar Binding. Does it have random variable? Yes, opposed Charisma check. Does it have a lot of variables, like for example "1 day per level maximum duration"? Also yes. Does it count? Is maximum duration increased?
Only RAW answers!

It affects numeric outcomes of dice rolls in the spell text
See the first paragraph of the feature

All variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell are increased by half including bonuses to those dice rolls.

"Those" in "those dice rolls" refers back to the "variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell", making it clear that those variable effects are from dice rolls.
I think this is meant quite literally: there should be a roll like 10d6 in the spell text, that would generate a numeric result, a number that could be scaled to increase the spell effect quantitatively, for example by causing more damage.
So Empower Metamagic does not apply to other variable effects that scale but are not generated by a die roll, like Planar Binding's duration, which depends on the caster's level, not a die roll in the spell description.
It also does not apply to rolls that do not generate a numeric outcome that can be scaled. In the example of Planar Binding, the opposed Charisma check does not result in a variable numeric outcome, it results in a qualitative outcome: one or the other side wins. Empower Metamagic does not apply to it, because there is no useful way that outcome can be "increased by half".

My doubt is that RAW, "all variable, numeric effects" is more than just dice rolls. Any value that is not static is a variable. Probably RAI it was meant to only affect dice rolls and their bonuses, but what about RAW? Is there anything that could clarify this? To those dice rolls wording is still as logical if some of the variables are dice rolls and some are not.

@NecXelis See my first paragraph. It is not all such effects, it is only dice rolls, because these „all effects" are back-refferred to as dice rolls.

This is how it works in previous editions as well.

The feat affects the rolled result, including any modifiers. For example, if a spell healed 2d8+10 (e.g. Cure Moderate Wounds cast by a level 10 character), it would instead heal 1.5*(2d8+10), giving a result between 18 and 39.
Note that it still only applies to effects that scale based on a dice roll. A spell that deals a flat 10+CL damage wouldn't be affected, nor would spells like Confusion that give discrete outcomes depending on a dice roll.
My source (credit to Fering for finding a reference to it): https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o71
In your example of Planar Binding, Empower would not apply. This is because the effect is not a random variable - you make an opposed Charisma check, but the outcome is simply a binary yes/no. There is no way to get 50% extra obedience! (This part relies more on interpretation than the first two paragraphs, but I think my interpretation is the logical reading of the rules.)

I question the math above only. Wouldn't CMW from a CL10 be 3d8+10? The 2d8 base healing 'increased by half' is 3d8 but the spell has a hard limit of +10 (specific rule overrides general) so it isn't +15 (not 100% sure on this one). A CL6 on the other hand... 3d8+9 healing from CMW.

@niekell You multiply the effect by 1.5; you don't add one extra dice and multiply the caster level by 1.5.

"All variable numeric effects... including bonuses to those dice rolls". I don't see this as the same as "times the result by 150%". Why mention dice rolls and bonuses? They are all the same in the "result". Increasing a variable numeric affect by half should increase the dice rolled by half. Take a Fireball from CL8, 8d6dmg, Empower it and it should do 12d6dmg. Nowhere does it say to multiply a result by half again, even the English wording would be odd if that was the intent of the Feat. Further example, a CL13 Wizard casting an Empowered Mage's Sword would do 6d6+4dmg per hit.

By 'variable' it means 'determined by a dice roll' - you can see that from the next sentence, "...nor are spells without random variables." It explicitly mentions bonuses to prevent the reader thinking they should ignore the modifier, since that would be an obvious source of confusion.

The number of dice is not multiplied because it is not a effect of the spell, it's how you determine the effect of the spell. The effect of the spell is 'do x damage' or 'do x healing' or 'summon x things', not 'roll x dice'. As a practical issue, if you think of the cases where you have an odd number of dice it becomes obvious that you can't increase the number of dice rolled by 50%.

The omission of RAW advice on anything to do with how to handle odd numbers of dice is just enough to convince me. I concede the point and will from now on rule it means 'times the result of dice and bonuses by 150%' in any games I GM. Thankyou for the correction.

It was a good question, I had to really think about the answer. They ought to have given an example in the rules to clarify this.
